# md5 does not match with downloaded ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64

Tags: system-installation, downloads, md5sum

I downloaded ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64 two times and the md5 does not match. Both are 904,192KB and I downloaded from the Ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) first and foremost.